# Dual Boot on different SSD, I want my 2 HDDs to be assigned to different 2 OS each when I boot one OS

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, dualboot

I am trying to create two environments. I want both OS to be Windows 10. One OS on one SSD and a second on another SSD.

One SSD will be for Games and the other for Work. I have two HDDs. I want to assign one for the gaming OS environment and the other for work.

So when I boot up for work I want one SSD and one HDD to work and others to sleep or not show up.

Answer (score 1):

To hide a partition you have to remove the associated letter.

Open the Disk Management utility (right click on the windows menu) --> right click on the partition(s) you don't want to show up --> Change driver letter --> Remove

Normally Windows won't remap the partition after reboot.

And you do that in both OS.